# Why does geometryFromEdges give a parse error when used in parfor on a thread-based pool?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I want to solve multiple PDEs in parallel on threads using the Parallel Computing Toolbox in Matlab. I have the following code:

```
delete(gcp('nocreate'));
parpool('threads')

parfor i = 1:1
    model = createpde();
     R1 = [3,4,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0]';
     sf = 'R1';
     ns = char('R1');
     ns = ns';
     gm = R1;
     g = decsg(gm,sf,ns);
     geometryFromEdges(model, g);
end
```

This results in the following error:

> Error using pde.EquationModel/geometryFromEdges
> The specified superclass 'pde.GeometricModel' contains a parse error,
> cannot be found on MATLAB's search path, or is shadowed by another file
> with the same name.
>
> Error in codeFile (line 4)
> parfor i = 1:1

When I change the `parfor` into a `for`, the code runs (and consequently I am able to numerically solve PDEs). The problem does not happen when I leave out `parpool('threads')`, and the parallel computations are done on processes.

I have already restored the default Matlab paths, the solution suggested for this type of error.

What could the problem be?

Comment: I have no idea how to solve your problem. However, a comment: why do you expect it to be faster in a `parfor`? MATLAB tends to use all your available cores/computational resources when being called to do inbuilt functions, why do you expect that a parallel for (i.e. running multiple solvers at the same time) will improve computational time?

Comment: I know that the performance is greatly increased when only working on physical cores because then the code runs without any error. I have seen that in general the performance does not increase when using hyperthreading as I want to do in this case, but I want to be sure that is the case also for my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MATLAB only supports a subset of functions in thread-based parallel computation, less than is supported in process-based parallel computation.  You can find the list [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/referencelist.html?type=function&capability=threadsupport).  It appears that `geometryFromEdges` isn't one of them.